# Redux Observable: How to return an action inside promise?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have an epic:

```
export default function uploadImage(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(userActions.UPLOAD_IMAGE)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      ...
      RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64').then(data => {
        firebaseRef.putString(data).then(snapshot => {
          console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
          return Observable.of(userActions.updateImageURL(snapshot.downloadURL)); //<----------
        })
      });
    })
};
```

However, this throws `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` with reason.

How would I wrap the callbacks inside an observable so that the epic doesn't break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In additionl to Maxime answer, in your example it appears the actual issue is that you're not really returning the Promise! You need to either return it or switch to using implicit return syntax for arrows

```
export default function uploadImage(action$, store) {
  return action$
    .ofType(userActions.UPLOAD_IMAGE)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      return Observable // don't forget to return this chain!
        .fromPromise(RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64'))
        .map(data => {
          firebaseRef.putString(data).then(snapshot => {
            console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
            return userActions.updateImageURL(snapshot.downloadURL);
          })
        });
```

This is a very common mistake, we've all been there!

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like that :

```
export default function uploadImage(action$, store) {
  return action$
    .ofType(userActions.UPLOAD_IMAGE)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      ...
      Observable
        .fromPromise(RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64'))
        .map(data => {
          firebaseRef.putString(data).then(snapshot => {
            console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
            return userActions.updateImageURL(snapshot.downloadURL);
          })
        });
```

Comment: hey @Maxime ! would i just nest `Observable.fromPromise` if i had multiple promises that depended on the results of the prior promise?

Comment: No it's the point with promise (and observables). You can just chain them :)